# Should constness propagate to member pointer pointees?

Tags: c++, pointers, coding-style, constants

I have a member function which is declared const and modifies data via a pointer. This seems misleading. Should I remove the const keyword?

I would like to know how others handle this situation in their code.  Do people just add a comment to clarify what is going on?  Do they not add the const keyword to the member function?  Maybe something else completely?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post an sscce? (see http://sscce.org/)

Comment: And how about simple example? Mb function should be const and variable in class should be mutable, mb function should not be const at all.

Comment: Think about what the function does: does it modify data that the user will think belongs to the object? If the answer is yes, then it should not be `const`; if the answer is no, then it should be `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have essentially two choices:

**Deep constness:**

```
class Foo
{
    T * ptr;
public:
    T       & operator*()       { return *ptr; }
    T const & operator*() const { return *ptr; }
    T       * operator->()       { return ptr; }
    T const * operator->() const { return ptr; }
};
```

**Shallow constness:**

```
class Foo
{
    T * ptr;
public:
    T & operator*() const { return *ptr; }
    T * operator->() const { return ptr; }
};
```

It's really up to you, and to the purpose of your class. If the class is a smart pointer, it would seem reasonable to have shallow constness semantics, since the class is supposed to be as similar to a raw pointer as possible (and you can of course have a constant raw pointer to a non-constant pointee).

Otherwise, you should ask yourself why you would be exposing access to a member pointer object at all. It's certainly possible that you want to give mutable access via constant references to your class, but I imagine those are special and rare circumstances. There shouldn't really be that many raw pointers in your code in the first place. Returning a deeply-const reference by dereferencing a pointer should be fine, but usually in better encapsulated "getter" functions which hide the fact that there is a pointer inside your class, like `T const & get() const { return *ptr; }`.

Comment: Note that the deep constness implementation still has a loophole, which is that you use a copy constructor on a `const Foo` to get a `Foo` with the *same* stored pointer, and then use the mutable interface (since it's not const anymore.)

Comment: @EdwardZ.Yang: Yes, true, the example is too elliptic. Your deeply-const type should not have an implicit copy.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, yes.  Its deceptive to modify something you are declaring constant, even though you can do it.

If someone uses your code and sees const, they expect const.  Modification, even though sensible to you, might cause them severe problems -- even crashing a program.

Comment: I'm agree at general, but not with `If someone uses your code and sees const, they expect const.`. How about mutable?

Comment: If I can't trust your const, I can't trust your code.  Yes, you can use mutable if its actually appropriate, but in general its not safe.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a `std::vector<Blah>` member versus a `Blah*` member used to implement a dynamic array. Most often it makes sense to replace the latter with the former. With the `Blah*` memeber a `const` method is allowed to modify the data in the array, while with the `std::vector<Blah>` member the `const` method is not allowed to modify data there.

Also consider a matrix class with an indexing method that returns a proxy that allows assignment to an element. Assigning via the proxy changes the matrix, not the proxy object itself. Thus, the proxy object’s assignment operator can be (and should be) `const`, in order to impose the most constraints possible on its effect, while its primary job is to modify things.

That’s another example that the design level is different from the coding level.

In the first example, with a member array, `const` was all about expressing a design level constraint, but in the second example, with the assignment proxy, `const` was all about expressing a coding level constraint.

These usages are not incompatible, however. The key idea is to provide a reader of the code with as many constraints as possible (because that greatly reduces how many varying things that must be considered to understand or deal with the code). Upshot: add `const` wherever you practically can.